# Twilio video conference application - Audio processing

Tags: javascript, webrtc, twilio, web-audio-api, actioncable

We are trying to create a video conference application using [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/video) javascript SDK and rails in back end. Where in the requirement we met was to automatically switch between speaking participants. We was able to process only one incoming audio stream at a time.

Here with have attached the code.

```
partcipant.media.mediaStreams.forEach(function(mediaStream) {
    var audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext)() || new(window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream);
    var script = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
    source.connect(script);
    script.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    script.onaudioprocess = function(event) {
      var input = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
      var i;
      var sum = 0.0;
      for (i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
        sum += input[i] * input[i];
      }
      var instant = Math.sqrt(sum / input.length);
      if (instant > 0.2) {
         console.log(participant.name + ' is speaking!');
      }
    }.bind(participant);
  });
```

We have used the above code in two logic:

1. Process the audio locally and send across channel using action cable.
2. Iterate the participants and process the audio stream.

Both worked, but application was crashing.

Please correct if I'm wrong at any point.

Comment: What do you mean, the "application was crashing"? What actually happened? Were there errors in the console? Did you just take down the entire browser?